# How can I intercept the content's of a window's spool file?

Tags: pdf, python, printing, printer, c#

I have files being printed from a client's computer and would like to intercept and archive the printed file as text or pdf. The client will most likely be using a specific software to print and I do not want to integrate with each of the different software's any client could be using.

Is there a way to intercept the content's of the print job, whether programmatically (python's win32print or wmi, c#, etc) or by converting the spool file (.spl & .shd) that is created in the C:\Windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS directory during print queuing.

Answer (score 0):

All print files in Windows are kept in the folder
`C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS`,
which requires Administrator permissions to access.

The files are in the format of `.SPL` files, which require a viewer.

As intercepting these files while they are being printed is hard,
you may instead ask Windows to keep them after printing, for you to copy
afterward. This depends on your printer having the option of
"Keep printed documents" in the printer Properties, usually in the Advanced
tab.

Some SPL viewers which might work for you:

- [SPLView](https://splview.software.informer.com/) (free)
- [O&K Printer Viewer](https://www.prnwatch.com/ok-printer-viewer/)
  (commercial)

Comment: Is there no way to do the conversion/viewing of the spool file programmatically? I would like to use ghostscript as a solution but I have not been able to successful convert a .spl or .shd file through it.

Comment: I have only found the above two viewers (I don't know if they do conversions). I also don't think that ghostscript supports SPL. You may try to find another product, but they seem somewhat rare.

Comment: I have looked for many solutions and havent found anything that fully solves the case that I have, even other products do not always work on the SPL files I have, which is weird. Is there anything else that I might need to know?

Comment: SPL format has evolved and not all products support all variants. I have not looked at costly commercial products like [VeryPDF SPL to PDF Converter](http://www.verypdf.com/app/hookprinter/spool-spl-to-pdf-converter.html), but you may if you have the budget for it.

Comment: I tried using the VeryPDF solution and also it would work on the example .SPL files that were provided but not the ones that came from my machine.

Comment: The format of SPL files may also depend on the type of the printer.

Comment: Is there no way to capture any of the possible SPL files? How do some virtual printers provide this capability?

Comment: hey... me too. I want to know 
how many pages printed and how many pages cancelled. Is there no SPL Reader alternatives? Perhaps the event viewer or something command line usage in windows @harrymc

Answer (score 0):

WMI c# ,DEVMODE and other party library sometime doesnt perform exactly etc totalPages, duplex or copies.
My solution is analysis SPL, in windows 10 you can open a SPL file using 7-zip or another software can read compressed file.

Comment: Your answer is not clear.